# Androidstudio Version3.4 can not open Project Structure

Tags: java, android

Androidstudio Version3.4 can not open Project Structure,it tips

Selected configuration element in the tree to edit its settings

Comment: Give us more information about your "project structure". What are you doing to produce this error?

Answer (score 0):

> Go to File > Project Structure > Modules.

Click on the **+** and add new module. select Phone and Tablet module.

Click next and then finish.

This should do the trick and the complete project structure will appear. It worked for me.